# get average for all numbers with irregular columns

Tags: awk, csh

Can `awk` deal with irregular columns? I.e. I have a file like below, in which each column may have a different number of values.

How to get the average of all the positive values?

Please note, the incomplete rows does not include blank/space, so you can not use `sed` to replace those blanks.

```
1 2 3 7
4 5
5 0
0 8 9
0
```

I know how to get average for regular files like below, but it will not work if the final row is not complete (4 numbers). Plus the code below can only print he average for each column separately.

I need an average for all non-zero numbers, not each column.

How to use `awk` or `python` to do that?

My expected output is one number: `4.888888889`
`((1+2+3+7+4+5+5+8+9)/9=4.888888889)`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i <= NF; i++) if ($i>0) { sum[i] += $i; num[i]++; } } END { for(i =1;i <= NF; i++) print i, sum[i]/num[i]}' $infile
```

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: You could loop over the elements of `sum` instead i.e. `END { for(i in sum) . . .`

Comment: @ RomanPerekhrest, just added, thank you for reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the average of all numbers in all columns, then this is simple

```
awk '   { for (i=1;i<=NF  ;i++){ sum+=$i;num++} }
     END{ print(sum/num) } ' infile
```

If you want the average per column, just keep track of the maximum number of columns:

```
awk '   {for (i=1;i<=NF  ;i++){ if(maxF<NF){maxF=NF};sum[i]+=$i;num[i]++} }
     END{for (i=1;i<=maxF;i++){ print(i,sum[i]/num[i]) } } ' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU **`awk`** approach:

```
awk -v FPAT='[1-9][0-9]*' '{ n += NF; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum += $i }END{ print sum/n }' file
```

The output:

```
4.88889
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert the spaces to newlines and have a single number per line:

```
tr ' ' '\n' <"$infile" | awk '$1 > 0 {n++; sum+=$1} END {if (n>0) print sum/n}'
```